# How to Moq class that is initialized in a method that you are testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a method that initializes another class and does something. I want to mock that intialized class and also verify its results. Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish

```cs
public class Foo{
   private string value; 
   public Foo(string: value){
      this.value = value;
   }
   public string DoSomething(){
      var barService = new Bar(value);
      return barService.DoSomethingElse();
   }
}

public class Bar{
   public string DoSomethingElse(string: value){
      return "You got a " + value ;
   }
}

public class Runner{
   public void run(){
      var foo = new Foo("drink");
      print(foo.DoSomething()); // will print "You got a drink"
   }
}
```

I am trying to write a test for `Foo.DoSomething()` but I need to mock `bar.DoSomethingElse()` and verify that Bar is initialized with the correct value.

Comment: There might be a better approach, but you might need to create a factory (perhaps just a `CreateBar` method) for creating `Bar`, and instead call that.

Comment: Does `Bar` class has some external dependencies, such as database query, accessing file system or web services?  If not - then don't mock it., because you will be able to verify that `DoSomethingElse` is called with correct argument by checking final result.

Comment: This cannot be done with Moq. You must use such heavy commercial tools as MS Fakes, TypeMock, JustMock. Or free, but less powerful and convenient: Prig, Pose, Harmony, etc.

Comment: I had a feeling it wasn't going to be possible :/ I could try modifying some stuff in the codebase to work around it

Comment: It's possible. But not with Moq. However, it is better to rework the design and inject the Bar class into the Foo class from the outside.

Comment: @Fabio makes a very valid point. Don't mock things that don't have dependencies. It's just wasteful.